# using FileReader to get image from phone camera/gallery on landing page

Tags: javascript, html, filereader, mobile-website

I've created this landing page that is triggered upon connecting to a router using `php`. It's got a simple form and one of the field is a qr reader. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/create-qr-code-reader-mobile-website/) to create the image uploader and decoder.

it was working fine when I'm running it on browser, but upon lodging it via landing page popup, on Android the file upload doesn't trigger and on iPhone, the landing page simply closes.

I suspect that this happens because on iPhone you usually can't navigate away from a landing page without closing it first and destroying the connection with the router. Hence, the deadlock.

here's the js file and html part of my code:

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head> 
            <title>QR Code Input</title>
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700i,700" rel="stylesheet">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles/index.css">
            <script type="text/javascript" src='./js/QRReader.js'> </script>
            <script src="./js/QRDecoder.js"> </script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" /> 
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="center">
            <img src="./img/logoCBN.png">
            <h1>
                    Hello $name!
                    <p id="subheader">Please enter your login code</p>
            </h1>
            <form action="goto.php" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="form" value="$form"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="$mac"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="password" value="$mac"/>
                    <input type=text size=20 name="qrcode" placeholder="Scan or enter login code" class=qrcode-text />
                    <label class=qrcode-text-btn>
                            <input type=file accept="image/*" capture=environment onclick="return showQRIntro();" onchange="openQRCamera(this);" tabindex=-1 />
                    </label> 
                    <p id="error"> $result </p>
                    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Login"/>
                    <!--Additional data-->
                    <input type="hidden" name="link-login" value="$link_login" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="link-orig" value="$desired_url" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="gateway" value="$gateway" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="lok" value="$location" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="dst" value="$desired_url"/>
            </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

JS:

```
function openQRCamera(node) {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function() {
  node.value = "";
  qrcode.callback = function(res) {
    if(res instanceof Error) {
      alert("No QR code found. Please make sure the QR code is within the camera's frame and try again.");
    } else {
      node.parentNode.previousElementSibling.value = res;
    }
  };
  qrcode.decode(reader.result);
};
reader.readAsDataURL(node.files[0]);
}

  function showQRIntro() {
    return confirm("Use your camera to take a picture of a QR code.");
   }
```

So my question is simple, is what I'm trying to do is even possible given the difference in nature between normal website and landing page in terms of file upload?

What I've tried so far is just to test and see if the JS part was even called and it was so I'm sure that it isn't the problem with the JS, it simply stopped doing anything upon reaching the file reader part and just escaped on Android and closes the page on iPhone.